# Don't rotate z-axis while rotating around Vector3.up and Vector3.left

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a Space Shuttle that i want to `rotate` on `Vector3.up` and `Vector3.left`, so that the player can look up/down and left/right with the Shuttle.

This is the code i use:

```
// Rotate the ship
transform.Rotate(Vector3.up, distX * rotateSpeed * Time.deltaTime, Space.Self);
transform.Rotate(Vector3.left, distY * rotateSpeed * Time.deltaTime, Space.Self);
```

where `distX` is a value for the strength of the rotation, based on `Mouse X` - Axis and `rotateSpeed` is just a value for the speed of the rotation.

However, if i use this script to rotate my ship, it gets rotated by the z-axis, too.

And i have no idea why it's doing this. These are the only lines in my code (yet) that do something with the rotation of the Shuttle.

What i tried yet is to replace `Vector3.up` by `transform.up` and `Vector3.left` by `transform.right` (also changed `distY` to `-distY` in the second case), but didn't work either.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/117147/lock-z-axis-from-the-gyroscope-rotation-unity-3d

Comment: You probably should start using _quaternions_ instead of euler angle rotations for reasons such as this.

Comment: @MickyD something like: transform.rotation = new Quaternion(transform.rotation.x + (distX * rotateSpeed * Time.deltaTime), transform.rotation.y + (distY * rotateSpeed * Time.deltaTime), 0, transform.rotation.w); ? - i get some really weird results on this

Answer (score 0):

You can assign Euler value of 0 to z like which allows you to restrict rotation in z axis :

```
    distX = Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * rotateSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
    distY = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * rotateSpeed * Time.deltaTime;       
    transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(distX, distY, 0f);
```